# SSRS report on web portal not able to click next page button after server upgrade from SQL Server 2014 to 2019

Tags: html, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, upgrade, sql-server-2019

The report server was updated from 2014 to 2019.

And I tried Edge and Chrome to visit web portal/Report Manager.

It does not let me click the next page navigation button. page shows 0/0.

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: So have you updated from SQL Server **2014** to 2019 - as mentioned in the title and with the tags - or from SQL Server 2016 to 2019, as mentioned on your question body??? Please be accurate and consistent in your statements

Comment: upgraded from 2014 to 2019

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please take a moment to re-edit your question so that it's useful for everyone. As @marc_s has commented_ there are different dates in title and post. This is an easy correction to make as per your comment _ Also, the images you have posted appear to be identical. Please remove one if it isn't necessary and edit the image description so that SO contributors know what they are looking at _ Thanks